# Service or Thread or AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

I need an advice for my latest app. It will show the user the latest subtitles released, and it will give him a notification in case new subtitles of his favourite series have been released; what should I use to achieve this?
I was thinking to create and run a service which will include a

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {...
```

but at the same time I really don't know how to make it interact with my app (if the app is opened I don't need any notification but I need to update the GUI).
I could use a thread but I'd like it to run it even after the main activity has been killed...
or I could use a AsyncTask so it would be easier to deal with the Application GUI.
Which solution should I use? I was thinking I should simply use a service (the first solution), but I'm not too sure about it, and furthermore I don't know if there is any way to make a service communicate with an activity periodically...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A service communicating with an activity is called **bound service**, that's what you should use IMO.

However, you say that when the activity dies, the service should keep running. But if the service is bound to your activity and the activity is dies, the service dies too.

I suggest you to read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) about it.

Check and see if you can bind a service to an activity, and when it dies, unbind and let the service continue to run independently.

If you can't, the activity could unbind itself, then start the service independently (with `startService` rather than `bindService`).

Answer (score 0):

if you are showing notifications, why not use C2DM messages for communicating with the app. The only thing would be that there would be popups shown to the user even if your app is not running. No need to use threads/services.